# Starting with a fresh DB directory in an AWS EC2 server with Bitnami Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I have set up an ec2 server on AWS & installed the Bitnami Wordpress package on it since it comes with many software (Apache, PHP, MySQL) that I want to use for developing my app.

Currently, the DB directory on phpMyAdmin looks like this:

[phpMyAdmin snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RABK6.png)

What I would like to do is have only my DB at the top level with sub-DBs underneath it at this directory level. I would like to avoid uninstalling the Bitnami package & installing MySQL, PHP & Apache separately (project preference). Is there any way for me to accomplish this?

I have tried to find articles online that solve this issue but have not found anything particularly relevant to my situation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it works, but you can do this.
First export your WordPress database to SQL file to your local machine
Then you should install all the components manually, including PHPMyAdmin, since you are using ec2 it will be easy to install with commands.
after all the installation import the SQL file and you will be able to access the WordPress app

hope it helps

Comment: My goal is to try to keep the Bitnami package for this project. Would I even be able to install fresh copies of MySQL, PHP, etc. when there's existing images of them in the Bitnami package?